# How to schedule multiple parallel jobs dynamically in Spring boot that scales to millions of users?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling, scalable

Tried using Quartz scheduler, but it doesn't scale well. I need to schedule jobs dynamically for each user that runs after one month or after few months based on user input.
Does anyone know which is the best option?

Comment: The typical approach would be NOT to schedule separate jobs for each user but rather run to schedule a single job (running daily or hourly). It does the work for all users that are due on the execution date or time. The job uses controlled parallelism (e.g. 20 threads) to run efficiently.

Comment: And I hope you are not *just* scheduling the job because what happens if your server crashes? Are the jobs lost? You should do as the other comment already said: have one job that runs periodically and does whatever you want to do to all users that match a given criteria,

Comment: @Codo Using one job that runs periodically seems to be the way to do it. Will try that using Apache Flink as I'm already using Flink in my project. Thanks !!